# Why do I get a configure error when installing MPIR?

Tags: visual-studio, gmp, mpfr, mpir, flint

I'm having a hard time because I've trying since three days to install the FLINT2 (Fast Library In Number Theory) library for c++ and use it in Visual Studio 2019. I discovered upon the reading of the documentation that I needed first to install three libraries upon which FLINT is depending, namely, MPIR, MPFR and GMP. Hence, I started to try installing them, it took me quite sometime before realising that these libraries were made for GNU systems. So, I had to install MinGW and msys in order to get it "compatible" and be able to use the commands ./configure, make, make check, etc.... After a while, I was able to install the GMP library. Next, the MPFR library was depending on the GMP one but I was able to install it by stating things like --with-gmp-include=... --with-gmp-lib=... and I also had to add --enable-static --disable-shared. Finally, I tried to install the MPIR library, however, YASM was missing from my computer apparently so I used the Windows Powershell to install Chocolatey. Then, I typed choco install yasm to install it and it worked!
I came back to msys and typed ./configure --enable-static --disable-shared to configure MPIR (it doesn't work without the enable/disable thing...) but then I get an error message, namely:

```
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for sysconf... no
checking for sysctl... no
checking for sysctlbyname... no
checking for times... no
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking whether vsnprintf works... yes
checking whether sscanf needs writable input... no
checking for struct pst_processor.psp_iticksperclktick... no
configure: error: no version of divisible_p found in path:  x86/nehalem x86 generic
```

Can I get some help please? I looked around but was not able to find any information about this kind of error! Apparently, the divisible_p function is a function defined in a C file called divis.c which can be found in gmp/mpn/generic/ but even when copying/pasting this file into the MPIR corresponding folder, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

So I successfully built and install the FLINT library in the msys folder because I needed either MPIR OR GMP so I did not need to install MPIR. However, I'm still intrigued by the reason about the divisible_p file missing...